# (OpenGL) Line is drawn but shapes are not

Tags: opengl

I'm currently learning OpenGL and from what I understood, I have to call

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
```

before drawing lines. Then, to draw shapes I need to call

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

to draw shapes such as GL_TRIANGLES and GL_QUADS.
I wrote this code with the goal of drawing a single line at top and 3 shapes, but only the line was drawn.
Here is my code.

```
void drawScene() {
//Clear information from last draw
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); //Switch to the drawing perspective
glLoadIdentity(); //Reset the drawing perspective



glBegin(GL_LINES);

glColor3f(100,200,100);
glLineWidth(10.0f);
glVertex2f(-1.0f,0.8f);
glVertex2f(1.0f,0.8f);

glEnd();

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

glBegin(GL_QUADS); //Begin quadrilateral coordinates

//Trapezoid
glVertex3f(-0.7f, -1.5f, -5.0f);
glVertex3f(0.7f, -1.5f, -5.0f);
glVertex3f(0.4f, -0.5f, -5.0f);
glVertex3f(-0.4f, -0.5f, -5.0f);

glEnd(); //End quadrilateral coordinates


glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); //Begin triangle coordinates

//Pentagon
glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, -5.0f);
glVertex3f(1.5f, 0.5f, -5.0f);
glVertex3f(0.5f, 1.0f, -5.0f);

glVertex3f(0.5f, 1.0f, -5.0f);
glVertex3f(1.5f, 0.5f, -5.0f);
glVertex3f(1.5f, 1.0f, -5.0f);

glVertex3f(0.5f, 1.0f, -5.0f);
glVertex3f(1.5f, 1.0f, -5.0f);
glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.5f, -5.0f);

//Triangle
glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, -5.0f);
glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.5f, -5.0f);
glVertex3f(-1.5f, 0.5f, -5.0f);

glEnd(); //End triangle coordinates

glutSwapBuffers(); //Send the 3D scene to the screen
}
```

Could someone please explain to me how to switch between GL_PROJECTION and GL_MODELVIEW and how do they work?

Comment: You use a deprecated fixed-function API. I highly recommend you to move to OpenGL 4.5, that will sort things out.

Comment: To hasten your learning you should learn more about the window and its coordinates, the OpenGL viewport, NDC and clip space. You won´t learn OpenGL properly by coding and see what happens. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Z-value of your polygons is `-5.0` which is outside the default [-1, 1] range for the device coordinates, so they get discarded.

Replace all `glVertex3f(x, y, z)` calls with `glVertex2f(x,y)`.

Comment: "culled" is an unfortunate term here. In OpenGL terminology, culling refers to eliminating polygons based on their winding order. What happens in this case is called "clipping".

Comment: @RetoKoradi: You are mistaken. Read OpenGL 4.5 spec section '13.5 Primitive Clipping': "Primitives are culled against the cull volume and then clipped to the clip volume"

Comment: Ok, technically the OpenGL spec uses the verb "discard" for this case (because the cull volume is not involved here). However, generally "culling" refers to dropping whole primitives whereas "clipping" refers to replacing primitives by smaller ones. So among the two its more of "culling" than "clipping". Still I'll align it with the OpenGL terminology.

Comment: I see, what you found is new in the 4.5 spec, and I wasn't familiar with it. It's a new feature for whole primitive culling introduced when the ARB_cull_distance extension was promoted to core. You won't find any of that language in specs before 4.5. Discarding geometry outside the view volume was always called clipping, and still is.